# Import library using npm angular2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, systemjs

I'm not able to setup [this library](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) using npm.

**Commands done :**

```
npm install ng2-charts --save
npm install chart.js --save
```

**index.html**

I added this line

```
        <script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
```

**app.module**

```
        import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(router),
        HttpModule,
        ChartsModule,

      ],
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'chartJS':                   'npm:ng2-charts'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      chartJS:{
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

**My console**

[image: console Error]

The content of this `localhost:3005/ng2-charts/ng2-charts` is in fact an HTML file - it refers to my `index.html`.

I'm not able to understand how it's working for hours now.

Comment: I don't think you have to add the script in index.html

Comment: no need to add in index.html if we are refering chart.js in system.config.js

Comment: @martin did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Your system.js config should be,

```
  map: {
    'chart.js': 'npm:chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js',
     'ng2-charts': 'npm:ng2-charts'
  }
```

and in packages,

```
 'ng2-charts': {
   main: 'ng2-charts.js',
   defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
```